# Extract Sqlite database when if the app is to be updated with different framework

Tags: sqlite, frameworks, android-sqlite, updates

I just started to learn how to use Flutter, and I have an app that is already developed with Android Studio.

So I am wondering if it is possible to extract Sqlite database of my Android Studio developed app and use that database if I update the app with Flutter?

Like, if I launch a new version of the app with Flutter i.e. making an another app that has exactly the same features then is there any possibility that I can extraxt database of Android Studio app and use it for the new one?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's the same App and therefore uses the same package then the database file will still be available and will be opened rather than created. That is the database is normally stored in the App's ***data/data/`<package>`/databases*** folder.